# Metadata and setup for curriculum vitae

Tags: cv, metadata

CVs have been one thing 20 years ago and are another today. As of today, CVs are automatically screened and analyzed, giving a cv that is not properly machine readable (or for the matter does not comprise the right kind of metainformation) a huge disadvantage.

hence, building a CV with meaningful, machine-readable metadata and data is of key importance.

first question (which might be a little bit OT): what metadata exactly is a CV typically screened for?

second question: how to punch in this metadata in the CV in LaTeX and what format should be used preferably?

Comment: The first question, while being extremely interesting, maybe belongs to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/.
The second, instead, appears to be a duplicate to this other question of yours: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539114/cv-internal-layout-for-machine-readability
Please consider keeping this one or the other, since one can be marked as duplicate, and eventually closed.

Comment: thanks for pointing to workplace.stackexchange.com - didnt know this page yet. regarding to your second comment: no, this is not what the other question is regarding. THIS question here is regarding to put information that would tell a CV-robot directly and unambiguously whats in the cv, while the latter is regarding the formatting the file